# Drush commands not defined - drush 11.4.0 drupal 9.5.1

Tags: drush

This configuration is working properly on xampp local install (drush version)

`Drupal version   : 9.5.1
DB driver        : mysql
DB hostname      : localhost
DB port          : 3306
Database         : Connected
Drupal bootstrap : Successful
PHP binary       : C:/xampp/php/php.exe
PHP config       : C:/xampp/php/php.ini
PHP OS           : WINNT
PHP version      : 7.4.27
Drush script     : C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/vendor/drush/drush/drush
Drush version    : 11.4.0`

But on webserver, any drush command I type (for example cr) returns a "Command "cr" is not defined."
Drush was installed via composer global require drush/drush (also exists as vendor/bin/drush in website root with same behavior)

drush list returns :

`Available commands:
help  Display help for a command
list  List commands`

I think I have pretty much the same config on another webserver with no such problem.
Any ideas on that ?

Comment: Global Drush installs are not supported.

Comment: Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency. https://www.drush.org/latest/install/

Answer (score 2):

Drush used to be installed globally, but that will no longer work. Instead, Drush LAUNCHER is installed globally. This creates a global `drush` command, however it does not contain the Drush code itself. The Drush code is instead added to each project on a per-project basis, managed using composer. When calling `drush`, Drush Launcher will take your current working directory, determine if it is a Drupal installation, and if it is, look for Drush in the vendor folder, and execute that on the current Drupal installation.

- Drush Launcher: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher
- Adding Drush to a project (from within the project folder): `composer require drush/drush`

Comment: Thank you Jaypan. I actually did it this way (but as I got The issue described above, I tried to add Drush globally also with no luck. But yes, drush launcher is in usr/local/bin and drush itself in my project root vendor folder. All files seems ok). Not sure what to do

Comment: Please re-read. Drush is NOT installed globally, and Drush launcher is NOT installed per-project. That is backwards. Drush launcher is installed globally, and Drush is launched on a per-project basis.