# "Command theme:uninstall was not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to run Drupal-specific commands."

Tags: commerce, drush

When I try to install or uninstall the theme via command, I am presented with the following error message.

> `Command theme:uninstall` was not found. Please provide the `--root` or a `@siteAlias` to execute Drupal-specific commands.

I am using Drupal 10.1.2, which is installed on a local XAMPP server. However, the command does not seem to be functioning as intended. Running the Drush produces the following notification.

> Note: Drupal root not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to see Drupal-specific commands.

I am using Drush 12.1.3.0.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm you are executing a drush from vendor/bin/drush and not a globally-installed drush?

Comment: Hi, I've installed Drush in the following directory: `/c/xampp/htdocs/drupal` using the command `composer global require drush/drush`. I'm uncertain whether it's being executed from the vendor directory or if it's installed globally. I'm new to Drupal and still getting familiar with the setup.

Comment: That is not installed or executed according to Drush's instructions: https://www.drush.org/12.x/install/

Comment: Global Drush doesn't work anymore. You need a local dependency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drush commands not defined - drush 11.4.0 drupal 9.5.1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/314369/drush-commands-not-defined-drush-11-4-0-drupal-9-5-1)

Comment: This also may duplicate this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/309273/how-to-fix-drush-installation-path-or-alias-to-drupal-root?rq=1